# How to copy OpenLDAP from SuSE to Debian Server?

Tags: ldap, debian, openldap, suse

I have to move an existing openldap installation from a SuSE Enterprise Server to an debian 7.8 server.

I have root access on both machines, and on the debian side I have a clean installation of slapd.
Just moving the /etc/openldap/* and /var/lib/ldap/* files from SuSE to /etc/ldap/ and /var/lib/slapd/ on the debian machine has had no success. Starting slapd on debian resulted in crc-checksum errors afterwards.

Is there any tutorial or good documentation online, where I can see, what steps I have to do?
I have to admit, that I have nearly no experience with openldap at all.

So, any help would be appreciated!

This is the failing entry:

```
dn: uid=TEST,ou=MyOU,dc=mydomain,dc=de
sn: test
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
objectClass: kvzXXX
objectClass: xxxExtended
xxxServiceType: MYWEBSERVICE_1_0
uid: TEST
xxxSOAPUrl: http://... entry
labeledURI: http://... 
xxxSOAP: FALSE
cn: mydomain
displayName: Test
xxxSOAPCertificate;binary:: BASE64
xxxServiceName: TestService
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: ...
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=de
createTimestamp: 20130311105718Z
xxxSOAPBackendUrl: http://...
```

Comment: Dump the source database as LDIF with slapcat, and load it at the target with slapadd.

Comment: I've tried using slapcat and slapadd, but wihtout success. 
On the source-machine, I've done "slapcat -v -l ldap.diff" and, after stopping ldap on the destination, I ran "slapadd -v -l ldap.diff". 
Then I got the following error:
 "slapadd: line 1: database #1 (dc=localdomain,dc=local) not configured to hold "dc=mydomain,dc=de"; no database configured for that naming context"

Comment: So I changed the database name, by using ldapmodify (after a google research), stopped ldap, and tried to run the above slapadd-command again. This time it looks better, but stops with the following error:
54e04994 str2entry: invalid value for attributeType objectClass #4 (syntax 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.38)
slapadd: could not parse entry (line=103)

In line 103 of the ldap.diff file, i found the following entry:
dn: uid=TEST,ou=MyOU,dc=mydomain,dc=de

So just using slapcat and slapadd seems not to be the right way for me :-)

Comment: Should work. Do you have the same schemas loaded in both installations? Can you post the entire entry that failed?

Comment: Hi have not installed the first server, so I have no idea, what schemas are loaded (and how to do so). Can you plaese give me a hint?

Comment: This is the failing entry:
dn: uid=TEST,ou=MyOU,dc=mydomain,dc=de
sn: test
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
objectClass: kvzXXX
objectClass: xxxExtended
xxxServiceType: MYWEBSERVICE_1_0
uid: TEST
xxxSOAPUrl: http://...
 entry
labeledURI: http://...
xxxSOAP: FALSE
cn: mydomain
displayName: Test
xxxSOAPCertificate;binary:: BASE64
xxxServiceName: TestService
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: ...
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=de
createTimestamp: 20130311105718Z
xxxSOAPBackendUrl: http://...

Comment: It's in the slapd.conf file if it has offline configuration, or under the slapd.d directory somewhere if it has online configuration. You'll have took up the OpenLDAP documentation. Clearly the source server has some extra objectClasses whose schemas aren't loaded in the target.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

It seems, that I've got a solution for my problem.

I have found some schema files on the source server, that looked very individual.
Because I was not able to load them with ldapadd, I switched the destination server from online configuration to offline configuration using slapd.conf. Then I was able to load the schemas and afterwards to import the database.